# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have created a django project for which i used MySQL database. I have mysql-python connector in mysql installed tools. I am not sure whether i set a required path in environmental variables. When i running the server, it raising an error : 
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'. I would appreciate helping me solve this.

Traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000000004F167B8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in    reraise
   raise value.with_traceback(tb)
 File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 199, in    import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 104, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in     _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 119, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
   self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table,  connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in    __getitem__
     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
   File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
   File "c:\python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 104, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 28, in <module>
     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module:     No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: when i do this it raises an another error - error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279. Currently i am using aws microsoft local server 2012. I am not user it have enough space to install microsoft c++ 10.0 is it. Thanks. Please help me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip install mysql-python` before making any migrations.